# create a unique list of emails in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code to insert an array of emails into the database.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$myEmails= array("Volvo@example.com", "BMW@example.com", "Toyota@example.com");

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


  foreach($myEmails as $email){

      $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (emails)
      VALUES ('$email')";

      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      echo "New record created successfully.!.";

  }


} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

All fine! Now what if we want to insert only emails into the table which doesn't exist in the table already.

I mean I want to insert the email into the table only if it isn't there...

**Note:** The purpose is to have a unique list of emails in the table... so maybe there is a solution to delete repeating emails in SQL also... I don't know!

I'm new to PHP. any ideas and suggestions would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm - work through this, and it should help you

Comment: Make the email column as unique (`PRIMARY KEY`) in you MySQL table and do `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a UNIQUE KEY on the `email` column (if not already done):

```
ALTER TABLE MyGuests ADD UNIQUE KEY (email);
```

Then use `INSERT IGNORE` syntax, to ignore all duplicate inserts. You should also use a prepared statement in a transaction, to improve both - performance and security:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO MyGuests (emails) VALUES (?)");

$conn->beginTransaction();

foreach($myEmails as $email){
    $stmt->execute([$email])
}

$conn->commit();
```

You can also remove duplicates in PHP with [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$myEmails = array_unique($myEmails);
```

This however will not prevent from inserting emails, which are already in the DB table.